# update state in react hooks with initalstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey i have the following data coming from api

```
0: {uuid: "a087b443-7af9-4464-8fd1-fb487fc60f66", name: "abc 19",}
1: {uuid: "baeb9282-84e9-4a72-b4e1-3a0ca6db7020", name: "abc 9", }
```

Basically it is an array.
Now i have a intial data like this this

```
[
    { id: 1, storeName: "Store First", toAdd: true },
  ]
```

now what i want to do using setState hook push the data coming from the api to intital State.

Here is what i did.

I used useEffect to make a call to api.The function is declared outside useEffect.In that function i tried prevState but it is pushing data like this.

```
0: {id: 1, storeName: "Store First", toAdd: true}
1: (2) [{…}, {…}]
2: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Following is the code i used

```
 const [list, setList] = useState([
    { id: 1, storeName: "Store First", toAdd: true },
  ]);


const getdata = async () => {
   
    const { response } = await api.getdata(); // This give the following response
     =========
     0: {uuid: "a087b443-7af9-4464-8fd1-fb487fc60f66", name: "abc 19",}
     1: {uuid: "baeb9282-84e9-4a72-b4e1-3a0ca6db7020", name: "abc 9", }
     =========
     ////

    setStoreList((prevstate) => [...prevstate, response]); //This set the following 
    =========
    0: {id: 1, storeName: "Store First", toAdd: true}
    1: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    2: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    =========
  };

    //Use Effect to call the function
     useEffect(() => {
        getdata();
      }, []);
```

What i accutally want

```
0: {id: 1, storeName: "Store First", toAdd: true}
1: {uuid: "a087b443-7af9-4464-8fd1-fb487fc60f66", name: "abc 19",}
2: {uuid: "baeb9282-84e9-4a72-b4e1-3a0ca6db7020", name: "abc 9", }
```

array of objects so that i can map over.

Comment: `setList([...list, ...response])`?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you're not spreading the response array, try replacing:

```
setStoreList((prevstate) => [...prevstate, response]); //This set the following
```

with

```
setStoreList((prevstate) => [...prevstate, ...response]); //This set the following
```

Since you're not spreading, everytime the hook runs it will append the responses array to `prevState`.

Comment: this works but the array getting incremented like in the initial it is 3 then increased by two and again..

Answer (score 0):

You can go for two ways here :-

**Using concat** :-

`setStoreList((prevstate) => prevState.concat(response))`;

`concat` helps you in joining the `prevState` and `response` array and get a new one.

**Using spread** :-

`setStoreList((prevstate) => [...prevstate, ...response])`;

**spread** operators let's all the **iterable** content be expanded in place so you are doing it correctly for `prevState` but forgot to do it for `response` which is also an `array`, thus an **iterable**.

Answer (score 0):

ES6: `setStoreList((prev) => [...prev, ...res])`
Or basically: `setStoreList((prev) => prev.concat(res))`